# Eclipse, Ubuntu - Eclipse IDE not starting (Well kinda)

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I am very experienced with eclipse, using it since its Juno days, but today i have ran into one of the strangest bugs and want to know if any of you have had this bug and if you may have an answer as to how to fix it. (Or at least a work-around to getting my favorite IDE working again).

I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and it seems nothing wants to work like it did when i had Wiley, namely eclipse. I used the installer to download the IDE and launched it and i got a strange issue where the IDE would load and ask for a workspace, but would then show a dialog box that is using the screen buffer as its data.

[Screenshot with strange eclipse launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfdwR.png)

I then thought that it may be an issue with the downloaded file (Corruption or something) so i downloaded the tar from eclipse.org directly. I extracted the tar and launched the eclipse executable and it loaded up and asked for a workspace again and began to launch, and finally it came up, the same old back buffered box.

So i got the idea to run it from the console and got this output, but i have no idea what it means. I saw no stack traces so im sure its fine (Again it may be a GTK error, so any ubuntu people this is where you come in)

[Console Run with the same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYL3F.png)

I started to think it was my java version (Oracle JDK 9 for Linux)that was the problem so i did a test compile of the hello world program and everything was fine, it all worked.

(Would add screen shots but im new here so i dont have enough reputation to do so :( )

Any idea what it might be? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, i installed the latest version of java in the apt repository. This version was JDK9 which Eclipse does not support (At least not until Eclipse Oxygen). I purged the computerof JDK9 and installed JDK8 and everything worked fine!

Moral of the story, don't use JDK9 on Neon

Answer (score 1):

I am running a dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, I have similar issue where I can see all the file menu and the eclipse launched on the tool bar, I have selected the application and  used ctrl+WindowsKey+left,right to split the application to half of my screen and then magically it appeared,Then I adjusted to fit to my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Would a fresh install work? I didn't have any issues. Perhaps ask this on ask ubuntu, too.

Comment: It is a fresh install of both eclipse and ubuntu (a graphics problem destroyed my xorg config settings and i just did a fresh install instead of dealing with the issue for any longer)